# Can't login to phpMyAdmin in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

got error #2002 - Connection refused
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: Can you provide more info? How exactly are you attempting to access it? Is it running alongside Apache, and if so is that working correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reviewing the three questions, chats and comments on your PHPMyAdmin issues, the error you are seeing is caused by mismatched versions of your depended packages.

PHPMyAdmin will work on Ubuntu 16.04 by installing the default packages from the repository without making any changes.

The two most important packages that needs to be matched is your version of **PHP**, the **PHP modules**, and **PHPMyAdmin**.

Other affected packages include:

**Apache2** and **Mysql**.

Purging those 5 packages and reinstalling them by their defaults will resolve your issue.

You can perform the quick method by first purging the PHPMyAdmin and PHP.  Rerun the purge command a second time to be sure it was actually purged.

The commands to purges **PHPMyAdmin** is:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin
```

The output after running those three commands should be similar to:

```
ljames@ubunzeus:~$ sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ljames@ubunzeus:~$
```

If the output is not clean, the purge command will have to be rerun.  Depending on the output, you might have to remove other packages that are causing the problem with getting a clean uninstall.

After that, do the same for php.  Check the versions you have installed and remove each one of them.

Run this to see which PHP versions are installed.

```
$ locate bin/php
```

You'll get something similar to:

```
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project1/webapp/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project1/webapp-backup/vendor/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project2/app/vendor/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php-cgi
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php-config
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/phpize
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php5
/user/bin/php7.0
/usr/bin/php5.3
```

Remove the packages that is `php` and `php[#]` as in this case `php5`, `php5.3` and `php7.0` are the packages to be removed:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge php5.3
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt remove --purge php5.3
```

Do that for the php versions until the output is clean similar to:

```
ljames@ubunzeus:/etc$ sudo apt remove --purge php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php7.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ljames@ubunzeus:/etc$
```

After you have removed the packages, reinstall the defaults with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php
$ sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

**Note:**
The text on the black screen console is very important.  It'll tell which packages are giving problems, and which package if any should be addressed.  Having the defaults install, will work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS